# `require': cannot load such file -- 2.6/ffi_c (LoadError) while running Flutter project on an M1

Tags: flutter, rubygems, cocoapods

I'm getting the following issue while running a flutter project on a M1 Mac.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core
    _ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- 2.6/ffi_c (LoadError)
```

I have tried uninstalling and installing the ffi gem as suggested in the Flutter docs.
The issue is still showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a workaround, still need to investigate if this is the appropriate solution. Run the following in your terminal to install the x86 gem.

`arch -x86_64 sudo gem install ffi`